# spark scala: Performance degrade with simple UDF over large number of columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-standalone

I have a dataframe with 100 million rows and ~ 10,000 columns. The columns are of two types, standard (C_i) followed by dynamic (X_i). This dataframe was obtained after some processing, and the performance was fast. Now only 2 steps remain:

Goal:

1. A particular operation needs to be done on every X_i  using identical subset of C_i columns.
2. Convert each of X-i column into `FloatType`.

Difficulty:

1. Performance degrades terribly with increasing number of columns.
2. After a while, only 1 executor seems to work (%CPU use < 200%), even on a sample data with 100 rows and 1,000 columns. If I push it to 1,500 columns, it crashes.

Minimal code:

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.FloatType

// sample_udf
val foo = (s_val: String, t_val: String) => {
    t_val + s_val.takeRight(1)
}
val foos_udf = udf(foo)
spark.udf.register("foos_udf", foo)

val columns = Seq("C1", "C2", "X1", "X2", "X3", "X4")
val data = Seq(("abc", "212", "1", "2", "3", "4"),("def", "436", "2", "2", "1", "8"),("abc", "510", "1", "2", "5", "8"))

val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
var df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd).toDF(columns:_*)
df.show()

for (cols <- df.columns.drop(2)) {
    df = df.withColumn(cols, foos_udf(col("C2"),col(cols)))
}
df.show()

for (cols <- df.columns.drop(2)) {
    df = df.withColumn(cols,col(cols).cast(FloatType))
}
df.show()
```

Error on 1,500 column data:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.isStreaming(LogicalPlan.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$isStreaming$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$isStreaming$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.exists(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:93)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.exists(List.scala:84)
...
```

Thoughts:

1. Perhaps `var` could be replaced, but the size of the data is close to 40% of the RAM.
2. Perhaps `for` loop for `dtype` casting could be causing degradation of performance, though I can't see how, and what are the alternatives.  From searching on internet, I have seen people suggesting `foldLeft` based approach, but that apparently still gets translated to `for` loop internally.

Any inputs on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A faster solution was to call UDF on row itself rather than calling on each column. As Spark stores data as rows, the earlier approach was exhibiting terrible performance.

```
def my_udf(names: Array[String]) = udf[String,Row]((r: Row) => {
    val row = Array.ofDim[String](names.length)
    for (i <- 0 until row.length) {
            row(i) = r.getAs(i)
    }
    ...
}
...
val df2 = df1.withColumn(results_col,my_udf(df1.columns)(struct("*"))).select(col(results_col))
```

Type casting can be done as suggested by Riccardo

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this will fix the performance on your side with 10000~ columns, but I was able to run it locally with 1500 using the following code.

I addressed points #1 and #2, which may have had some impact on performance. One note, to my understanding `foldLeft` should be a pure recursive function without an internal for loop, so it might have an impact on performance in this case.

Also, the two for loops can be simplified into a single for loop that I refactored as `foldLeft`.

We might also get a performance increase if we replace the udf with a spark function.

```
  import spark.implicits._
  import org.apache.spark.sql.types.FloatType
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

  // sample_udf
  val foo = (s_val: String, t_val: String) => {
    t_val + s_val.takeRight(1)
  }
  val foos_udf = udf(foo)
  spark.udf.register("foos_udf", foo)

  val numberOfColumns = 1500
  val numberOfRows = 100


  val colNames = (1 to numberOfColumns).map(s => s"X$s")
  val colValues = (1 to numberOfColumns).map(_.toString)

  val columns = Seq("C1", "C2") ++ colNames
  val schema = StructType(columns.map(field => StructField(field, StringType)))

  val rowFields = Seq("abc", "212") ++ colValues
  val listOfRows = (1 to numberOfRows).map(_ => Row(rowFields: _*))
  val listOfRdds = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(listOfRows)
  val df = spark.createDataFrame(listOfRdds, schema)

  df.show()

  val newDf = df.columns.drop(2).foldLeft(df)((df, colName) => {
    df.withColumn(colName, foos_udf(col("C2"), col(colName)) cast FloatType)
  })

  newDf.show()
```

Hope this helps!

*** EDIT

Found a way better solution that circumvents loops. Simply make a single expression with `SelectExpr`, this way sparks casts all columns in one go without any kind of recursion. From my previous example:

instead of doing fold left, just replace it with these lines. I just tested it with 10k columns 100 rows in my local computer, lasted a few seconds

```
  val selectExpression = Seq("C1", "C2") ++ colNames.map(s => s"cast($s as float)")
  val newDf = df.selectExpr(selectExpression:_*)
```

Comment: The CPU usage reflects very low cache-hit ration. Row-wise approach might be the solution.

Comment: Does the issue persist with the `df.selectExpr` approach I added in the edit?

Comment: Thank you for the help. The `cast` issue is not primary concern as the computation itself was crashing and I can read from the csv file into which I can dump the data (in the worst case). However, being able to do that would help in continuing the computation skipping the intermediate step. The computation failure is surprising, and once I figure out how to fix it (most likely through shifting to row-wise computation), I will use this very useful tip to accomplish the task.